# Leave objects surface colour on another surface object after interaction

Tags: materials

Could one leave an objects surface colour on another surface object after interaction.
I want to splash paint onto a white canvas, essentially paint within blender (Static image result). Quite difficult to search for this...

Comment: Not quite what you want, but it might be worth investigate Dynamic Paint in Blender. Something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrw7-cbtQBA) might give you a few ideas.